# "cannot find -lQt5Core -lQt5Gui etc" when using other not related libraries

Tags: c++, qt, boost, qt5, qmake

ISSUE SOLVED (scroll down)

Im on windows 7 and compilling with MinGW.

I made a new Qt application in QtCreator 3.01 (Qt 5.2.1). I compile it, the empty application window pops up everything is awesome. But as soon as i use any other library (like boost or gtest) im starting getting these errors when compiling

```
cannot find -lqtmain
cannot find -lQt5Widgets
cannot find -lQt5Gui
cannot find -lQt5Core
```

ld returned 1 exit status

This is my .pro file

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-04-19T14:17:24
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Thermovision
TEMPLATE = app

include(Model/Model.pri)
include(Controller/Controller.pri)
include(View/View.pri)
include(Interface/Interface.pri)


SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

HEADERS  += \
    logdebug.h

FORMS    +=

OTHER_FILES += \
    Model/Model.pri \
    View/View.pri \
    Controller/Controller.pri \
    Interface/Interface.pri \
    Globals/zGlobals.pri

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../Downloads/boost_1_54_0/boost_1_54_0/stage/lib/ -lboost_thread-mgw48-mt-1_54
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../Downloads/boost_1_54_0/boost_1_54_0/stage/lib/ -lboost_thread-mgw48-mt-1_54d
```

this is the main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>
#include "View/form.h"
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Form w;
    w.show();

    boost::thread b;

    return a.exec();
}
```

when i comment usage of boost thread, the include and the part in .pro file responsible for finding boost thread library everything compiles again. Same when im trying to use gtest.

The odd thing is that I havent found any information regarding this issue anywhere on the internet :<

Can someone help me?

=================================================================================
[SOLVED]
ok so it seems qt wanted me to explicitly add the libraries into project. I used the built-in tool which generated the following output

```
win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../../Qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/mingw48_32/lib/libQt5Core.a
else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../../Qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/mingw48_32/lib/libQt5Cored.a
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../../Qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/mingw48_32/lib/Qt5Core.lib
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../../Qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/mingw48_32/lib/Qt5Cored.lib
```

but im sure one can thin it down (im gonna stay with this)

Comment: Why do you have so many unnecessary whitespaces at the end where you have LIBS? Also, why do you use double quotes for the boost thread include as opposed to system-wide < ... > ?

Comment: the spaces are when i was copy pasting the 4 spaces to make it look as code here on forum.

Comment: I mean in the LIBS variable, not in general. Do you have those spaces in your original code, too? If yes, remove them. Also, did changing the include from "..." to <...> make a difference in my previous comment? If that helps in any way, I will try to submit it as a proper answer. Currently, I am unsure at this stage.

Comment: [This code](http://paste.kde.org/pvyxjtbzm) works for me on Linux. Try to get it work on your Windows with mingw because it is much simpler than your complicated code base. Once that works, you can move on to your code base.

Comment: i have to add 

    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include
    DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include

For it to let me include boost. Also this


    LIBS += -lboost_thread -lboost_system

causes 

    :-1: error: error: unrecognized command line option '--lboost_thread-mgw48-mt-1_54'

Comment: Yes, it is written for Linux, so you need to port it to your environment, replace LIBS with your LIBS content, add INCLUDEPATH, etc. Does it work afterwards?

Comment: Once i make it look like this http://screenshooter.net/0155138/tugpcuv
I start getting the same error as usually (cant find Qt5* libraries)

Comment: Extra Information:
I tried making a non QT application and use boost thread in it. Everything works fine (had to add boost system to the libraries on the way).

So i think its something wrong with Qt. When im trying to compile a Qt application it doesnt even reach the point when it screams for boost system. Oddly as i said everything runs smoothe if i use QT windows and not use any boost / gtest library

Comment: Can you remove the dependpath? I do not think you need that here.

Comment: I did. Nothing changed.
I also reinstalled qt creator to make sure its minGW version. No difference in behavior either 
When i open help->about qt creator it says "Based on QT 5.2.1(MSVC 2010, 32bit)". Shouldnt it say MinGW instead of MSVC? Im sure i installed a mingw version

Comment: Ok thanks for your help Laszlo Papp . I found solution i will post it as answer once i can (with my reputation it takes 8 hours before you can answer your own question). Edited the question so far.

Comment: I submitted the answer, but I still think it is just a workaround, not a solution. Dynamic libraries should work, too. Marcin, does `LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../Qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/mingw48_32/lib/` make it work with the original code base?

Comment: Yes this line makes the code compile and work correctly - as far as i can say such thing about aplication that is not doing anything yet.

I can even remove / comment those 4 lines i pasted before. Basicly now the only 3 lines mentioning anything about qt are 
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../Qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/mingw48_32/lib/

Interesting thing -> if i add (...)/mingw48_32/BIN instead of /mingw48_32/LIB it reduces the number of libraries not found to only  -lqtmain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our comments and outcome, it seems that a quick solution is to add the libraries explicitly that you wish to use. It will generate something like this in the background, so basically using static libraries as opposed to dynamic:

```
win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../../Qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/mingw48_32/lib/libQt5Core.a
else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../../Qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/mingw48_32/lib/libQt5Cored.a
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../../Qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/mingw48_32/lib/Qt5Core.lib
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../../Qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/mingw48_32/lib/Qt5Cored.lib
```

Alternatively, which I would personally suggest more is to add the following line for now in your project file to get this working with dynamic libraries rather than static to make your application binary go up to the hill:

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../Qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/mingw48_32/lib/
```